# xcode swift NSFileManager: remove file from /Library

Tags: swift, cocoa, permissions, filesystems, nsfilemanager

I need to remove files from /Library/... folder, but got an Error message:

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "%filename% couldn’t be moved to
>   the trash because you don’t have permission to access it."

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    // Check if file exists
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
        // Delete file
        do {
            try fileManager.trashItem(at: url, resultingItemURL: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    } else {
        print("File does not exist \(url.path)")
    }
```

How can i obtain permissions to do that? There is other ways to remove files?

Comment: do you want to remove all files?

Comment: No, actually, i need to remove from /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins

Comment: This is obviously macOS. Is you app sandboxed?

Comment: Yes, this is macOS and app is sandboxed.

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902995/read-and-write-permission-for-user-selected-folder-in-mac-os-app