# macOS Security scoped URL bookmark for folder

Tags: swift, macos, appstore-sandbox, security-scoped-bookmarks

I'm experiencing problems (on Mojave and Catalina) with "reusing" security scope URL bookmark for a folder between app launches in my app.

It's simple decompressing application using `libarchive` framework. User selects file to decompress, I want to store URL bookmark for it's parent folder (e.g. ~/Desktop), and reuse it next time user tries to decompress file in the same folder.

First, I added following to my app's entitlements file:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
```

**When accessing file (parent folder respectively) for the first time:**

1. User selects file to decompress
2. I present `NSOpenPanel` to obtain access to the file folder:

```
let directoryURL = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent()

let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
openPanel.prompt = "Grant Access"
openPanel.directoryURL = directoryURL

openPanel.begin { [weak self] result in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    // WARNING: It's absolutely necessary to access NSOpenPanel.url property to get access
    guard result == .OK, let url = openPanel.url else {
        // HANDLE ERROR HERE ...
        return
    }

    // We got URL and need to store bookmark's data
    // ...
}
```

3. I obtain bookmark data of **folder** URL and store it to keyed archive:

```
let data = try url.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
bookmarks[url] = data
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(bookmarks, toFile: bookmarksPath)
```

4. Now I start using **file** URL and use `libarchive` to decompress .zip file to it's parent folder:

```
fileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
// Decompressing file with libarchive...
fileURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

5. Everything is working as expected, .zip file gets decompressed

**When relaunching app, decompressing file in the same folder, reusing saved bookmark data:**

1. I get bookmarks from keyed archive:

```
let bookmarks = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: bookmarksPath) as? [URL: Data]
```

2. I get bookmark data from bookmarks for the file's parent folder and resolve it:

```
let directoryURL = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
let data = bookmarks[directoryURL]!
var isStale = false
let newURL = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: data, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
```

3. Now again I start using **file** URL and use `libarchive` to decompress .zip file to it's parent folder:

```
fileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
// Decompressing file with libarchive...
fileURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

But this time `libarchive` returns error saying `Failed to open \'/Users/martin/Desktop/Archive.zip\'`

I know I might be doing something terribly wrong or not understanding concept of security scoped URL bookmarks but can't find where's the problem. Any hints?

**FINAL SOLUTION**
Both Rckstr's answer and answer in [this Apple developer forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124687) pointed me into the right direction. It's absolutely necessary to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` on THE SAME INSTANCE of URL returned by `try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: data, options: .withSecurityScope ...`

Comment: No need to use sandbox. Hope this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75274173/5646794

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're resolving the security-scoped bookmark (for the directory) to `let newUrl`, but you call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` on the file's URL `fileURL`. You need to call it for `newURL`.

```
newURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
// Decompressing fileURL with libarchive...
newURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

Two more remarks:

1. When obtaining access through NSOpenPanel, you don't need to call
   `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` and
   `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`, because the user explicitly
   granted you access for this session.
2. I use `var isStale: ObjCBool = ObjCBool(false)` instead. I'm no Swift expert, so not sure if `var isStale = false` is ok to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it's not working. I resolve bookmark for the folder (e.g. `/Users/martin/Desktop/`) and start accessing it instead of the fileURL, but still can't access resources in the folder. FYI when calling `folderURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` the return value is false. Any other hints?

Comment: In fact, you're right. The problem was I wasn't calling `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` for the same URL instance. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since I cannot comment I create a new answer.
Just a gotcha: The NSArchiver doesn't do any magic and is not strictly necessary. You can store the URL how ever you want for example in user defaults:

I do like this:

```
private func handleURLReceivedFromOpenPanel(_ url: URL) throws -> Void {
    let data = try url.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
        
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.writableUrl)
        
    guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
            fatalError("Failed starting to access security scoped resource for: \(url.path)")
    }
}

func getStoredUrl() throws -> URL {
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.writableUrl) else {
        // no url stored so return a url that can be accessed
        return try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("someSubfolderOrWhatever")
    }
        
    var isStale = false
    let newUrl = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: data,
                         options: .withSecurityScope,
                         relativeTo: nil,
                         bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
      
    guard newUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
        throw Error("Could not start accessing security scoped resource: \(newUrl.path)")
    }

    return newUrl
}
```

If you are storing the URL in memory remember to release the resource with

```
oldUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

Comment: I found this example very helpful.