# SwiftUI: How to save URL-Bookmarks with security scope

Tags: security, url, swiftui, scope, bookmarks

```
.fileImporter( isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [.image,.pdf], allowsMultipleSelection: true, onCompletion: { result in
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let files):
            fileURL = []
            files.forEach { file in
                let gotAccess = file.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                if !gotAccess { return }
                if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: file),
                   let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    images.append(image)
                }
                fileURL = files
                file.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

The fileURL could be e.g. @ApplicationStorage("url's").
How can I use the fileURL later? I think that I have to store them as bookmarks with SecuritySscope, but I don't know how to do.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for helping hints.
Peter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ask for the Documents permission in a sandboxed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776305/ask-for-the-documents-permission-in-a-sandboxed-app)

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`fileImporter(isPresented:allowedContentTypes:allowsMultipleSelection:onCompletion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fileimporter(ispresented:allowedcontenttypes:allowsmultipleselection:oncompletion:)), SwiftUI returns security-scoped URLs where you need to state when you're accessing a resource (you can only have so many open before the system starts rejecting your requests).

If you want persisted access to a URL (where you can access it even when your app exits), you'll need to create a bookmark for the URL via [`bookmarkData(options:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/2143023-bookmarkdata), passing at least `.withSecurityScope` to the options parameter. Note that, depending on the kind of access you need, you may need to pass more information. For example, if you only need read access to a URL, also pass `.securityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess` to the options. And if you plan on working with an arbitrary amount of URLs (say, up to the thousands), you should also pass the `.withoutImplicitSecurityScope` option.

Whenever you want to retrieve the URL for the bookmark, create a URL with the [init(resolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeTo:bookmarkDataIsStale:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126805-init) initializer. Many of the options map well to the options used when creating a bookmark, but at the very least, you'll need to pass `.withSecurityScope`. An extra parameter you'll need to pass is a var for determining when the bookmark has expired, in which you're expected to create a new bookmark from the returned URL.

For your case, it may look something like this:

```swift
struct Bookmark {
  let data: Data
  let options: URL.BookmarkCreationOptions
}

struct URLBookmark {
  let url: URL
  let bookmark: Bookmark
}
```

```swift
.fileImporter(isPresented: $isPresenting, allowedContentTypes: [.image, .pdf], allowsMultipleSelection: true) { result in
  switch result {
    case .success(let urls):
      let items = urls.compactMap { url -> URLBookmark? in
        let data: Data
        let options: URL.BookmarkCreationOptions = [.withSecurityScope, .securityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess, .withoutImplicitSecurityScope]
        
        do {
          let accessing = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
          
          defer {
            if accessing {
              url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            }
          }
          
          data = try url.bookmarkData(options: options, includingResourceValuesForKeys: [])
        } catch {
          print(error)
          
          return nil
        }
        
        return URLBookmark(url: url, bookmark: .init(data: data, options: options))
      }
      
      items.forEach { item in
        let accessing = item.url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        
        defer {
          if accessing {
            item.url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
          }
        }
        
        // Do something...
      }
    case .failure(let err):
      print(err)
  }
}
```

Then, when you want to create the URL from the bookmark, you could have some code like so:

```swift
let bookmarks: [Bookmark] = ...
let items = bookmarks.compactMap { bookmark -> URLBookmark? in
  var options = URL.BookmarkResolutionOptions()

  if bookmark.options.contains(.withSecurityScope) {
    options.insert(.withSecurityScope)
  }

  if bookmark.options.contains(.withoutImplicitSecurityScope) {
    options.insert(.withoutImplicitStartAccessing)
  }

  var stale = false
  let url: URL

  do {
    url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmark.data, options: options, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &stale)
  } catch {
    print(error)

    return nil
  }

  let data: Data

  if stale {
    do {
      let accessing = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()

      defer {
        if accessing {
          url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
      }

      data = try url.bookmarkData(options: bookmark.options, includingResourceValuesForKeys: [])
    } catch {
      print(error)

      return nil
    }
  } else {
    data = bookmark.data
  }

  return .init(url: url, bookmark: .init(data: data, options: bookmark.options))
}

// Now do something with items...
```

How you store the bookmarks is up to you. It could be in a file on disk, a Core Data store, in `@SceneStorage` or `@AppStorage`, etc. I would personally suggest that if you plan on potentially storing a lot of bookmarks (say, over 200), you should stay away from the storage property wrappers as they write to `UserDefaults`, and bookmarks can start to take a lot of storage (1-8KB each).

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your URLs as Bookmark Data. This type keeps security scoops when retrieving again data back:

```
do {
   let bookmarkData = try yourURL.bookmarkData(options: .minimalBookmark, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
                        
   yourVariableToSave = bookmarkData
   } catch {
   print(error)
}
```

More info on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fcpxml_reference/asset/media-rep/bookmark/creating_bookmark_data). And on this session of WWDC 2019: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/719

Comment: This only works for basic bookmarks, and not security scoped bookmarks (which at least needs the `URL.BookmarkCreationOptions.withSecurityScope` option)